# NGINX redirect complete domain HTTP + HTTPS to single file

Tags: nginx

Can someone please help me out on how to redirect a complete domain (http + https) to a single index.html file?

The website is gone, but there are still a lot of backlinks that somehow magically are being redirected to other websites on the same server.

Thus I would like to add back my server blocks but redirect all traffic from this specific domain to a single HTML file.

Domain: https://nieuwsvertaald.nl/

My current code:

```
server {
    if ($host = nieuwsvertaald.nl) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name nieuwsvertaald.nl;
    root /var/www/nieuwsvertaald.nl;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


}


server {

    listen 443;
    server_name nieuwsvertaald.nl;
    root /var/www/nieuwsvertaald.nl;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nieuwsvertaald.nl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nieuwsvertaald.nl/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

In the folder I have a single index.html file.
Can anyone help me out on how to redirect any URL within this domain to the index.html in the root folder?

I dont understand why when I visit https://nieuwsvertaald.nl/ it shows a different website. I need to stop this from happening.